# Looking to prove that, for $0\le a<b<c\le\frac\pi2$, $\cos(b)\cos(c)(\sin(c)-\sin(b))+\cos(a)\cos(b)(\sin(b)-\sin(a))>\cos(a)\cos(c)(\sin(c)-\sin(a))$

Tags: trigonometry

Looking to prove that for $ 0 \le a < b < c \le \frac \pi 2 $,

$$ \cos ( b ) \cos ( c ) \big( \sin ( c ) - \sin ( b ) \big) + \cos ( a ) \cos ( b ) \big( \sin ( b ) - \sin ( a ) \big) \\
> \cos ( a ) \cos ( c ) \big( \sin ( c ) - \sin ( a ) \big) \text . $$

This crops up in trying to show the Haar condition is satisfied on $ \left[ 0 , \frac \pi 2 \right] $ for the basis functions $ 1 $, $ \cos ( x ) $ and $ \sin ( 2 x ) $. This comes up in a course I'm doing on approximation theory. I'm reasonably confident it is true, and have investigated numerically using MAPLE, but haven't so far been able to prove the statement formally. Any suggestions on how to progress gratefully accepted.

Comment: As you may know, the Math.SE community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 1):

define $ f : D \to \mathbb R $ with
$$ f ( a , b , c ) = \\
\cos b \cos c ( \sin c - \sin b ) + \cos a \cos b ( \sin b - \sin a ) + \cos c \cos a ( \sin a - \sin c ) \tag 0 \label 0 \text , $$
where $ D = \left\{ ( a , b , c ) \in \left[ 0 , \frac \pi 2 \right] ^ 3 \Big| a < b < c \right\} $. You're asking for a proof of $ f ( a , b , c ) > 0 $ for all $ ( a , b , c ) \in D $. The trick is to rewrite \eqref{0} as
$$ f ( a , b , c ) = \\
2 \sin \left( \frac { c - b } 2 \right) \sin \left( \frac { b - a } 2 \right) \sin \left( \frac { a - c } 2 \right) \big( \cos ( a + b + c ) - \cos a - \cos b - \cos c \big) \text . \tag 1 \label 1 $$
Knowing this, you can note that $ \frac { c - b } 2 , \frac { b - a } 2 , \frac { a - c } 2 $ are all in $ \left[ - \frac \pi 4 , \frac \pi 4 \right] $, which is an interval on which the value of sine function at a point has the same sign as that of the point itself. Also, $ b , c , \frac { b + c } 2 \in \left[ 0 , \frac \pi 2 \right] $ and $ a + \frac { b + c } 2 \in \left[ 0 , \pi \right] $, and $ \cos ( a + b + c ) - \cos a = - 2 \sin \left( \frac { b + c } 2 \right) \sin \left( a + \frac { b + c } 2 \right) $. These,  together with $ a < b < c $, show that $ \sin \left( \frac { c - b } 2 \right) > 0 $, $ \sin \left( \frac { b - a } 2 \right) > 0 $, $ \sin \left( \frac { a - c } 2 \right) < 0 $ and $ \cos ( a + b + c ) - \cos a - \cos b - \cos c < 0 $, which by \eqref{1} shows that $ f ( a , b , c ) > 0 $.

Comment: The expression in \eqref{1} is given by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28b%29cos%28c%29%28sin%28c%29-sin%28b%29%29%2Bcos%28a%29cos%28b%29%28sin%28b%29-sin%28a%29%29%2Bcos%28c%29cos%28a%29%28sin%28a%29-sin%28c%29%29). I suppose getting to it is a tedious task of repeatedly applying sum-to-product and product-to-sum formulas.